# JAVA update Database - wrong

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public abstract class Query {

    private static final String DRIVER_CLASSNAME = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static final String USERNAME = "";

    protected static String base = "data/pezalDB";
    private static String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:" + base + ".db";

    protected static Connection connection;
    protected static Statement statement;
    public static ResultSet resultSet;

    public static void connectToDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASSNAME);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }

    public static void executeSql(String sql) throws SQLException {

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    }

    public static void close() throws SQLException {
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }

}

public class TableDB {

    private int id;
    private String namePL;
    private String nameEN;

    public TableDB(String namePL, String nameEN) {
        this.namePL = namePL;
        this.nameEN = nameEN;
    }
}

public class QueryMethods extends Query {

    static String table = "dictionary";
    static String sql;

    public static void addValue() {
        try {
            connectToDatabase();

            sql = "UPDATE dictionary SET namePL = 'QWE' WHERE id = 2";

            executeSql(sql);
            close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addValue();

    }
}
```

I have a problem :

```
java.sql.SQLException: query does not return ResultSet
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeQuery(JDBC3Statement.java:85)
    at application.QueryMethods.addValue(QueryMethods.java:18)
    at application.TestQuery.main(TestQuery.java:10)
```

What is wrong? When I read from database all is ok but more function is wrong.

Did not work Update and Insert
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you supply the SQL query please? My guess is that there is an issue there. Perhaps you didn't execute a SELECT statement but rather an update/insert. That would explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to execute a SQL UPDATE statement with the executeQuery() method. executeQuery() cannot take statements that update the database, such as UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE. Replace this line with:

```
int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```